# Why do X-ray binaries such as GRS-1915 have active and quiet states?

Tags: black-hole, binary-star

X-ray binaries such as GRS-1915 feature a black hole and a regular star. The x-ray luminosity is likely related to the rate of mass flow into the black hole from the star so when there is a lot of mass flow the x-ray luminosity is high but this explanation seems to just beg the question as to why the mass flow would change over time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such objects are surrounded by an accretion disk, that is a disk of gas, the gas being accreted onto the central object. However, at this stage of its life, the accretion disk around the black hole of a binary system like GRS-1915+105 is strongly depleted. Therefore, the accretion rate is not sufficient to support a coutinuous burst. Matter fills the outer disk until a critical density is reached, that triggered an outburst. Mass from the companion star is lost by a [Roche lobe overflow mechanism](http://astronomy.swin.edu.au/cosmos/R/roche-lobe+overflow).

**References:**

- X-ray binaries in general: [Remillard & McClintock 2006](http://cdsads.u-strasbg.fr/abs/2006ARA%26A..44...49R)
- For the outburst X-ray transients in particular: [Dubus et al. 2001](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2001A%26A...373..251D)